# How to show every files in code::blocks Projects tab

Tags: codeblocks

In the projects tab I can only see the main.c file

[image]

But in this directory I have other files, how do I make them appear on the projects tab?
[image]

Comment: This question doesn't seems to be related to `c` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can:

- Select `Add files recursively...`.
- Select the directory of your project.
- Add interesting files to your project.

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]